# Is there a better string method than 'title' to capitalize every word in a string?

Tags: python

This capitalizes even the letter after the apostrophe which wasn't the intended result,

```
>>> test = "there's a need to capitalize every word"
>>> test.title()
"There'S A Need To Capitalize Every Word"
```

some people suggest using capwords, but capwords seems to be crippled(only
capitalizing words preceded by whitespace). In this case I also need to be able to capitalize words separated by periods (eg: one.two.three should result on One.Two.Three).

Is there a method that doesn't fail where capwords and title do?

Comment: Think about regular expression , I do not think that there is such a think already to use in python

Answer (score 3):

Use [string.capwords](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.capwords)

```
import string
string.capwords("there's a need to capitalize every word")
```

Comment: yes but capwords only works if the words are preceded by whitespace, this doesn't work for example 

>>> test = "there's.a.need.to.capitalize.every.word"
>>> string.capwords(test)
"There's.a.need.to.capitalize.every.word"

Comment: I am afraid there is not existing function suitable for your needs then. You should re.sub everything you consider to be a delimiter and then apply capwords.

Comment: isn't this better than capwords ?

`code`def capitalizing(test):        
    return " ".join(w.capitalize() for w in test.split())`code`

Comment: @noob81: no, it's not. You end up with the side effect of removing periods, as well as capitalizing the words.

Comment: What about the separator option on capwords? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-capwords-method/

Comment: `string.capwords` have a parameter `sep=None` by default is whitespace. you can replace with `.` for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

There's a solution to your exact problem in python's docs, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

```
>>>
>>> import re
>>> def titlecase(s):
...     return re.sub(r"[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?",
...                   lambda mo: mo.group(0)[0].upper() +
...                              mo.group(0)[1:].lower(),
...                   s)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use anonymous function in the replacement part of `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "there's a need to capitalize every word"
>>> re.sub(r'\b[a-z]', lambda m: m.group().upper(), test)
"There'S A Need To Capitalize Every Word"
```